# Accessing uninform <dt></dt> <dd></dd> tags

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, dataframe

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get("http://www.walmart.com/search/?query=marvel&cat_id=4096_530598")
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "tile-content"})

data=defaultdict(list)


for tile in g_data:
#the "tile" value in g_data contains what you are looking for...
#find the product titles
    try:
        title = tile.find("a","js-product-title")
        data['Product Title'].append(title.text)
    except:
        data['Product Title'].append("")

#find the prices
    try:
        price = tile.find('span', 'price price-display').text.strip()
        data['Price'].append(price)  
    except:
        data['Price'].append("")

#find the stars
    try:
        g_star = tile.find("div",{"class" : "stars stars-small tile-row"}).find('span','visuallyhidden').text.strip()
    data['Stars'].append(g_star)
except:
    data['Stars'].append("")

    try:
        dd_starring = tile.find('dd', {"class" : "media-details-multi-line media-details-artist-dd module"}).text.strip()
        data['Starring'].append(dd_starring)
    except:
        data['Starring'].append("")

    try:
        running_time = tile.find_all('dl',{"class" : "media-details dl-horizontal copy-mini"})
        for dd_run in running_time :
            running = dd_run.find_all('dd')[1:2]
            for run in running :
             #print run.text.strip()
                data['Running Time'].append(run.text.strip())
    except:
                data['Running Time'].append("")

    try:
        dd_format = tile.findAll('dd',{"class" :"media-details-multi-line"})[1:2]
        for formatt in dd_format:
        data['Format'].append(textOfFormat)
    except:
         data['Format'].append("")

    try:
        div_shipping =tile.find_all('div',{"data-offer-shipping-pass-eligible":"false"})
        data['Shipping'].append("")
    except:
        freeshipping = "Free Shipping"
    data['Shipping'].append(freeshipping)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

---

I want to access the

which if without a class name. How to access it?

Like row no.11 has 5

director field and few other have

Release date.

Currently I am accessing it using [2:1] and so on.. But its not flxible and doesnt populate my table correctly.

Any function to do this?

Comment: it is difficult to understand your description. Could you clarify which fields you want to access? "Running time" or "Stars"?

Comment: I want to access all the <dt></dt> <dl></dl> elements but as I populate the table.. since the dl and dt are not uniform in the order they are place in <div class='tile-aside-content'> I get actor name in the running time and at times actor name in format.

Comment: I have added the inspect element html code as an image.    so <dd>127 minutes </dd> comes without the class name.. So SInce theres no way I know of other than using id and class name of accessing it , I made the code look at only 1 and 2nd <dd> elements.If there is a added <dd> of director then the <dd>  tag of running time goes down and the data in table gets populated with actors ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute Staring and Running time with:

```
try:
    dd_starring = tile.find('dd', {"class" : "media-details-artist-dd"}).text.strip()
    data['Starring'].append(dd_starring)
except:
    data['Starring'].append("")

try:      
    running = tile.find('dt',{'class':'media-details-running-time'})
    running_time = running.find_next("dd")
    data['Running Time'].append(running_time.text)
except:
            data['Running Time'].append("")
```

This should run now. It seems that when you select multiple classes with BeautifulSoup it can get confused so you can get the Actors just by css class `media-details-artist-dd`. For the running time I employed a simple trick :)

**EDIT:** Changed the code to find the `dd` for Running Time and then get the next sibling. The previous code had an extra unneeded part

It should work now

Comment: I didnt work . all the rows for Running Time were empty.                                            I guess checkng if <dt> is present and then only print <dd> below that <dt> should work.

Comment: I had an extra part. Not sure that this caused the problem. It should work now

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in replying. My network was down. Yes. find_next("dd") worked :)   Thank you